# Unable to call new file in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have created new module, which populate information from database. 
this information will be displayed inside the grid. when the specific record is click light popup will be display.new PHP file is (showdetails.php) assigned to light box.

```
<td><a class="modal" href="showdetails.php" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 680, y: 370}}" >POPUP</a></td>
```

POPup working fine. but inside popup, i am not getting " Not Found " error.

What is the rule to follow for popup or external file access.

showdetails.php contain below code

> defined('_JEXEC') or die; echo "Hello world";

Answer (score 3):

If the `showdetails.php` file is not loaded using the Joomla framework, then the constant `_JEXEC` is not defined and your script will `die`.

So don't use `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` and try again.

If it still fails, make sure to reference the file correctly.

Edit: According to your comments I think you got a bigger problem here. If you want to use Joomla functions within your `showdetails.php`, you would have to initialise the whole Joomla framework first, otherwise db and such things will not be available.
Usually such a popup loads a component view using an URL like `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&layout=popup&tmpl=component`. This way the Joomla framework is loaded and you have access to each Joomla function. Basically within Joomla, you never load a standalone file directly for output. Everything goes through the index.php and is loaded from there.

Comment: what is that reference ? how should i know joomla framework loaded showdetails.php file , i should enter this showdetails.php anywhere.

Comment: if i removing of this defined('_JEXEC'), then i loose DB and all joomla connections and activites

Comment: `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` is just a security check that a Joomla file is loaded within the framework. If you directly load a file, then it's not loaded within the framework.

Comment: i beleave this one applicable for module as well.
I have Some quries: 
i dont have any view page (PHP File), so what should i write instead of this. (view=myview)
i have showdetails.php only, But i dont have layout (PHP File), what should i replace instead of this. (layout=popup)
what should replace tmpl=component instead of ?

index.php?option=mod_mymodule&view=myview&layout=popup&tmpl=component

Comment: If you want to generate an output in its own page using Joomla, you need a component with a view and everything. That's what components do. Or you do everything in your showdetails.php using plain PHP without Joomla functions. Or you could initualize the Joomla framework within your showdetails.php. Or you could build the page during the loading of the module, but hidden. And instead of loading a separate file you just show the hidden element. There are many ways, just your current one will not work :-)